# Is there any third party component for XML Tree viewer for .NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml

I am looking for a third party component that can display XML tree and when you click on of the leaf will expand more tree.

This component will be used in .NET web application (ASP.NET).

I am appreciated your feedback.

Comment: There's no such thing as a ".NET app". What GUI framework are you using? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? Silverlight?

Comment: All that I have seen, as completely rubbish. (for ASP.NET)

Comment: Any suggestion then? I am thinking to use the treeview BUT it will be nice to have something that can expand (like XML Spy).

Comment: Pretty sure XML Spy wasn't written in ASP.NET. It can just use the native Windows controls, like the TreeView. That's why it's important to specify these things in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telerik

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

ExtJs

http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-6 ([xml tree](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2/examples/tree/xml-tree.html))